# fstream deleting specific start to end rows

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

Im a noob programmer currently making a small family database using cpp but i have trouble deleting a family from the the list...

My list looks something like this

```
start-of-family 1
jim
joe
bob
sam
end-of-family 1
start-of-family 2
rob
max
end-of-family 2
start-of-family 3
sue
tom
kim
end-of-family 3
```

If i wanted to delete family 1, I would locate start-of-family 1 and end-of-family 1. Then run a loop but how do i locate it if the user only inputs an int to represent a family number. Also how do i make the succeeding family numbers deduct by 1 so that family 2 will be 1 and family 3 will be 2.

thanks a lot

Comment: The standard way to modify a data file is to read records from the file, optionally process the part you have read, and then write the result to a new file. Repeat until all done, then rename the files. There is no other reasonable way to insert or delete things in the middle of a text file.

Comment: just got back. and realized that, that logic is way better. im closing this thread now and instead of modifying the database ill just clear it and update it with what i have in my program. Its way better, thanks dude

Answer (score 2):

If I were doing this problem I would start by making each family into a vector of names. Then, I would create a vector containing those family vectors.

The result would look something like:

```
{  
<(jim), (joe), (bob), (sam) >  
<(rob), (max) >  
<(sue), (tom), (kim) >  
}
```

Then, if the user wants to delete one of the families, you can use vector.remove(n) where n is the index of the family to be removed.

This sounds like a school or text book assignment. Have you gotten to vectors yet? Where are the names coming from? Are you hard coding them into the list? Or reading them from a .txt file? What kind of list structure are you storing them in right now?

Comment: I have a class controlling the inputs and so they are not hardcoded into the txt file but written into it. We havent gotten into vectors yet  and i dont think we ever will. fstream wasnt even discussed to us at all it just simply appeared in the project manual instructions. Apparently my teacher is lazy af

Comment: This isnt even 90% of the proper list. Becasue my real list has specifics like father mother children address contact no email age sex and all that stuff. Im just focusing on deleting a whole family data because thats what trying to tackle so far

Answer (score 0):

i realized that clearing the db and updating it with what ive got is way easier than modifying the db and updating my program

Comment: You better use the comment part for this.